# How to add multiple column headers that span specified columns to a DT table rendered in Shiny?

Tags: css, r, json, shiny, dt

I'm looking for examples of how to add multiple column headers to a table rendered with `DT` table in R Shiny but the examples of how to do this can be convoluted. Mostly adding JS and CSS but it can be difficult to pick out what are the necessary items to include in your code to add the column headers to the table.

So let's start with this super-simple code example below. How to add multiple column headers, following the illustration below where I added mock headers in blue to show what I'm trying to add for the sake of example? Black font is fine, I only used blue to delineate what I added using Paint versus what was rendered by Shiny. Boxes around the headers are helpful.

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl'))
  
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tbl = renderDT(iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE))
  }
  
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After synthesizing some of the other SO posts, here's a solution using CSS. Not as easy as XLS which is where I come from and what I am always trying to mimic! What I didn't realize before is that you can stack column-spanning headers on top of each other by using multiple `tr()` statements in building the container code as I do in the code below, with each added header spanning a different number of columns. This is a very nice feature. Here's an illustration of the results:

[image]

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

myContainer <- htmltools::withTags(table(
  class = 'display',
  thead(
    tr(
      th(style = "border-top: none;border-bottom: none;"),
      th(colspan = 6,'Plant facts',
         class = "dt-center",
         style = "border-right: solid 0.5px;border-left: solid 0.5px;border-top: solid 0.5px; background-color:#D9D9D9;"
      )
    ),
    tr(
      th(style = "border-top: none;border-bottom: none;"),
      th(colspan = 4,'Lengths and widths',
         class = "dt-center",
         style = "border-right: solid 0.5px;border-left: solid 0.5px;border-top: solid 0.5px; background-color:#E6E6E6;"
         )
    ),
    tr(
      th(style = "border-top: none;"),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Sepals', 
         class = "dt-center",
         style = "border-right: solid 0.5px;border-left: solid 0.5px;border-top: solid 0.5px; background-color:#F2F2F2;"
         ),
      th(colspan = 2, 'Petals', 
         class = "dt-center",
         style = "border-right: solid 0.5px;border-left: solid 0.5px;border-top: solid 0.5px; background-color:#F2F2F2;"
         ),
      th(colspan = 1, '', 
         style = "border-right: none;border-left:none;border-top:none;border-bottom:solid 0.5px;"
      )
    ),
    tr(
      th(),
      lapply(names(iris), th)
    )
  )
))

ui <- fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl'))

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT(
    iris, 
    container = myContainer,
    options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```